# CPU utilisation goes to 100% while processing a text file

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, file-io

I have a master account file having more than 300000 records. This file is having Office, FA, UUID fields along with other fields. We have a webservice which retuns currently enrolled offices for pilot.

I need to generate a output file with unique UUIDs from master account file which are part of pilot. The below is my code.

```
public class Job
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> UUIDOfficeFA = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    static Dictionary<string, string> UUIDs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    static string PilotOfficeList = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void RunJob()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AccountFileFolder"]);
            if (directoryInfo != null || directoryInfo.Exists == false)
            {
                FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
                DateTime lastWrite = DateTime.MinValue;
                FileInfo lastWritenFile = null;
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                      if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
                        {
                            lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
                            lastWritenFile = file;
                        }

                }
                if (lastWritenFile != null)
                {
                   if (RetrieveUUIDs(lastWritenFile))
                    {
                        WriteFile();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("No matching account file found for processing");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }

    }

    static void WriteFile()
    {
       try
        {

            string FileName = "Testfile_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
            string Path = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TestFolder"] + @"\" + FileName;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in UUIDs)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(kvp.Value);
            }
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(Path))
            {
                writer.Write(sb.ToString());
                writer.Flush();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }

    }


  static bool RetrieveUUIDs(FileInfo file)
    {
       try
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
            {

                string accountFileData = null;
                accountFileData = sr.ReadToEnd();

                string[] str = accountFileData.Trim().Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                List<string> AccountInfo = new List<string>(str);

                if (AccountInfo.Count > 0)
                {
                    TestWebservice client = new TestWebservice();
                    GetBrancheListRequest request = new GetBrancheListRequest();
                    GetBrancheListResponse response =client.GetBrancheList(request);

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        PilotOfficeList = response.GetBrancheListResult;

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PilotOfficeList))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("No branch is enrolled for pilot");
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (string accountInfo in AccountInfo)
                {
                    RetrieveUUID(accountInfo);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          throw ex;
        }
       return true;
    }

    private static void RetrieveUUID(string line)
    {
        try
        {
            string UUID = line.Substring(2, 50).Trim();
            string Office = line.Substring(444, 3).Trim();
            string FA = line.Substring(447, 3).Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PilotOfficeList))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UUID) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Office))
                {
                    if (PilotOfficeList.IndexOf(Office) > -1)
                    {
                        if (!UUIDOfficeFA.ContainsKey(UUID + Office + FA))
                        {
                            UUIDOfficeFA.Add(UUID + Office + FA, UUID + Office + FA);
                            if (!UUIDs.ContainsKey(UUID))
                            {
                                UUIDs.Add(UUID, UUID);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

The issue is when this program runs the CPU utilisation goes to 100%. Although entire job completes within 2 minutes but i can't move this on server beacuse it might cause issue for other apps. Please suggest how i can optimize this so that CPU doesn't goes to 100%.

Thank you so much for your help in prior.

Note- It appears that following are few major CPU utilization points

```
1-
accountFileData = sr.ReadToEnd();
2-
string[] str = accountFileData.Trim().Split(new string[] { "\n" },    StringSplitOptions.None);
3-
foreach (string accountInfo in AccountInfo)
{
         RetrieveUUID(accountInfo);
}
```

Comment: All those nested calls to `.IndexOf` and `.ContainsKey` are probably where the problem is if your master lists are 300k large.  Suggest you get a profiler like dotTrace and use it; you can't guess your way out of a performance problem.  You have to profile and find exactly where your bottlenecks are.  That said, if you have a file with 300 thousand entries and you're trying to manage it with generic lists, it's probably time to start thinking about investing in a database.

Comment: Add `Thread.Sleep` :)... What is the problem of using available CPU?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is pointless. It does nothing but hide the original stack trace (showing the *actual* exception.) Either eliminate the `try`/`catch` or change the body to just `throw;` which will re-throw the original exception.

Comment: I hope you have checked that your program is the only thing that is consuming all the CPU resource. No other project/program is running simultaneously. More over your workstation and server would have different configuration. The number of processes on server and your work station will be different. One more thing you can do is debug a specific method which might be a culprit. you can comment out one method after other and find out the method which is causing high cpu usage and then remediate the culprit.

Comment: Why a text file?  Why not a database?  Spending a couple of minutes parsing the file and doing manual joins and such is a waste of time when it can be achieved with an SQL server in a much shorter time - milliseconds, if your tables and indices are correctly configured.  So... why not use a database?

Comment: J...- Will try to use dot trace and find out bottlenecks. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Any further suggestions ???

Comment: I think the suggestion of moving this data into a database is the best one.  Using a text file is just a bad idea for this much data.  Storing it in generic lists is also a bad idea.  They're not meant for this kind of work - a database is.  VS lets you use local files with SQL Server Compact - this is the obvious way forward for this problem.